# Put Pandas Dataframe into influxDB

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series, influxdb

I would like to put this DataFrame ([DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv3p1.png) ) into influxdb. Unfortunately I have the following error message: ***"ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."***

Trouble with this 2 lines?

- tags         = { 'tag1': df[['tag1']], 'tag2': df[['tag2']]  }
- client.write_points(df, 'test', tags = tags)

  I do not understand why. Thank you for your help

  ```
     def main(host='10.0.0.3', port=8086):
          """Instantiate the connection to the InfluxDB client."""
      user = ''
      password = ''
      dbname = 'ess_2'
      protocol = 'line'

      client = DataFrameClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)

      print("Create database: " + dbname)
      client.create_database(dbname)

      t = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
      headers = ['time','tag1','tag2','field1','field2']
      data    = [[t,'MSFT','NYSE',1.3,2.5],[t,'APPL','NYSE',3.5,4.24]]
      df      = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = headers)
      df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
      df      = df.set_index('time')
      tags        = { 'tag1': df[['tag1']], 'tag2': df[['tag2']]  }   #DEBUG
      client.write_points(df, 'test', tags = tags) #DEBUG



      print("Read DataFrame")
      client.query("select * from demo")


  def parse_args():
      """Parse the args from main."""
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
          description='example code to play with InfluxDB')
      parser.add_argument('--host', type=str, required=False,
                          default='10.0.0.3',
                          help='hostname of InfluxDB http API')
      parser.add_argument('--port', type=int, required=False, default=8086,
                          help='port of InfluxDB http API')
      return parser.parse_args()
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       args = parse_args()
       main(host=args.host, port=args.port)
  ```